# методы TRACE, CONNECT

Tags: http, rest

Для какой цели в HTTP стандарте были введёны методы TRACE, CONNECT?

Comment: Rest api? разве нет?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков я тоже изначально так думал. Но, нет https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP

Comment: 1) Вики не показатель. 2) Список методов из стандарта не ограничивает вас в праве создавать новые методы =) Допустим про `TRACE` нагуглить сходу удалось что это нечто вроде трасировки по цепочке проксей, тогда как `CONNECT` что ни на есть тунелирование внутри http =) Ответ из вики: Сервер может использовать любые методы, **не существует обязательных методов** для сервера или клиента. если что из вики - второй абзац в разделе "методы"